# Auto adjust product tax class based on WooCommerce category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to update the tax class based on the category being set. I need to use the Reduced Rate for everything in my category "Books". The category ID is 133, and I'm currently using this filter, but it's not working. What am I missing here?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_product', 'change_tax_for_books' );

function change_tax_for_books( $id ) {
    if( has_term( 133, 'product_cat', $id ) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $id );
        $product->set_tax_class( 'Reduced Rate' );
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

I'd like to add my WordPress is in Dutch, do I have to use "Gereduceerd Tarief" in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Got it! There were a few issues. First off, apparently products are initialized by WordPress before CRUD so `woocommerce_new_product` is pretty misleading. It's better to use `woocommerce_update_product`.

Next up, when using that you will get in an infinite loop because every time you call `save()`, the action runs again, so you need to remove your action and then add it again. See the final code below.

```
function change_tax_for_books( $id ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $id );
    
    if( has_term( 133, 'product_cat', $id ) ) {
        $product->set_tax_class( 'Gereduceerd tarief' );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'change_tax_for_books' );
        $product->save();
        add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'change_tax_for_books' );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'change_tax_for_books' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's a `filter` and not an `action`.  Did did a quick scan and only found refs to an action called `woocommerce_new_product`:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_product', 'change_tax_for_books' );
```

Comment: Ah, I thought you could add filters and actions to "do_action". How would you update the tax class based on category?